Junit for the elastic search ParsedFilter
I am trying to cover Junit for elastic search ParsedFilter.
Code:
    private void returnDeviceColumnValues(List<String> uniqueColumnValues, NativeSearchQuery searchQuery) {
    SearchHits<ESDashboardEntity> searchHits = operations.search(searchQuery, ESDashboardEntity.class);
    ElasticsearchAggregations aggregations = (ElasticsearchAggregations) searchHits.getAggregations();
    List<Aggregation> aggregationList = aggregations.aggregations().asList();
    aggregationList.forEach(agg -> {
        if (agg instanceof ParsedNested nestedAgg) {
            Aggregations subAggs = nestedAgg.getAggregations();
            ParsedFilter parseFilter = (ParsedFilter) subAggs.get(DashboardConstant.FILTER_AGG);
            ParsedStringTerms terms = parseFilter.getAggregations().get(DashboardConstant.UNIQUE_VALUES_AGG);
            for (Terms.Bucket bucket : terms.getBuckets()) {
                uniqueColumnValues.add(bucket.getKeyAsString());
            }
        } else if (agg instanceof Terms terms) {
            for (Terms.Bucket bucket : terms.getBuckets()) {
                uniqueColumnValues.add(bucket.getKeyAsString());
            }
        }

    });
}

Junit Code:
@Test
void testReturnDeviceColumnValues_WithParsedFilter() throws IOException, MTValidationException {
    TypeReference<FilterColumnValuesDTO> typeReference = new TypeReference<>() {
    };
    FilterColumnValuesDTO deviceInput = BaseConverter.build("deviceFilterRequest.json", typeReference);

    NativeSearchQuery searchQuery = mock(NativeSearchQuery.class);
    TypeReference<ESDashboardEntity> dashboardTypeReference = new TypeReference<>() {
    };
    ESDashboardEntity deviceOutput = BaseConverter.build("ESDashboardEntity.json", dashboardTypeReference);
    String deviceInputString = mapper.writeValueAsString(deviceInput);
    ParsedNested nestedAgg = mock(ParsedNested.class);
    ParsedFilter parsedFilter = mock(ParsedFilter.class);
    ParsedStringTerms terms = mock(ParsedStringTerms.class);
    Aggregations subAggs = mock(Aggregations.class);
    when(aggregations.aggregations()).thenReturn(subAggs);
    when(nestedAgg.getAggregations()).thenReturn(subAggs);
     when(subAggs.get(DashboardConstant.FILTER_AGG)).thenReturn(parsedFilter);
    Aggregations filterSubAggs = mock(Aggregations.class);
    when(parsedFilter.getAggregations()).thenReturn(filterSubAggs);
    
    List buckets = new ArrayList<>();
    Terms.Bucket bucket1 = mock(Terms.Bucket.class);
    when(bucket1.getKeyAsString()).thenReturn("value1");
    buckets.add(bucket1);
    when(terms.getBuckets()).thenReturn(buckets); // Executing the method
    List<ParsedNested> aggregationList = Collections.singletonList(nestedAgg);

    when(operations.search(Mockito.any(NativeSearchQuery.class), Mockito.eq(ESDashboardEntity.class)))
            .thenReturn(searchHits);
    List<SearchHit<ESDashboardEntity>> searchHit = new ArrayList<>();
    searchHit.add(new SearchHit("1", "1", null, 0, null, null, null, null, null, null, deviceOutput));
    when(searchHits.getSearchHits()).thenReturn(searchHit);
    when(searchHits.getTotalHits()).thenReturn(1l);
    when(searchHits.getMaxScore()).thenReturn(1.0f);
    when(searchHits.getAggregations()).thenReturn(aggregations);
    when(aggregations.aggregations()).thenReturn(new Aggregations((List<? extends Aggregation>) aggregationList));
    when(searchHits.getAggregations()).thenReturn(aggregations);

    String encodeToString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(deviceInputString.getBytes());
    DeviceColumnFilterValuesDTO deviceColumnData = deviceService.getDeviceColumnData(encodeToString);

    assertNotNull(deviceColumnData);
}

I am getting below exception. The subAgg is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.size()" because "this.aggregations" is null
at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.Aggregations.getAsMap(Aggregations.java:74)
at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.Aggregations.asMap(Aggregations.java:66)
at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.Aggregations.get(Aggregations.java:88)
at com.mt.retail.dashboardservice.service.DeviceServiceTest.testReturnDeviceColumnValues_WithParsedFilter(DeviceServiceTest.java:374)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:95)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:91)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:60)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)


Did you mean to comment out 3 lines that start with //  when(aggregations.aggregations()).thenReturn(subAggs); ?

@imotov If I enable this comment line I am getting
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.size()" because "this.aggregations" is null
at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.Aggregations.getAsMap(Aggregations.java:74)
at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.Aggregations.asMap(Aggregations.java:66)
at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.Aggregations.get(Aggregations.java:88)
at com.mt.retail.dashboardservice.service.DeviceServiceTest.testReturnDeviceColumnValues_WithParsedFilter(DeviceServiceTest.java:374)

Your filterSubAggs is not setup in any way. So, my guess would be it fails in the last get in this line:
ParsedStringTerms terms = parseFilter.getAggregations().get(DashboardConstant.UNIQUE_VALUES_AGG);


yes you are right. I am not sure how to set the aggregation to nestedAgg

You can continue doing the same thing you did for previous mocks. The same thing that you did for subAggs.
